# React component with html text

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to render react components with html, and my react component must listen states, but I can`t do it..

```
{component} = <span>ComponentText</span>
```

I have something like this and this Array can be in different orders and different combinations, for example:

```
let result = ['<div><p>123', {component}, '</p></div>', {component}];
```

With "dangerouslySetInnerHTML", I have:

```
123[Object][Object]
```

Without "dangerouslySetInnerHTML":

```
<div><p>123ComponentText</p></div>ComponentText
```

I`m looking for result like this:

```
123ComponentTextComponentText
```

And my states and events with this component must work well, Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

In React, you don't deal in HTML snippets like your `result` array, you deal in *objects*.

But you can use JSX to do something similar to what you want, just not with isolated bits of text in an array:

```
let result = [<div><p>123<Component /></p></div>, <Component />];
```

Live Example:

```js
class Component extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.state = {
      value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
    };
  }
  render() {
    return <span>I'm a component, this.state.value = {this.state.value}</span>;
  }
}

let result = [<div><p>123<Component /></p></div>, <Component />];

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>{result}</div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

To illustrate that you're still dealing with objects despite using JSX, here's what that JSX transpiles to:

```
var result = [
    React.createElement(
        "div",
        null,
        React.createElement(
            "p",
            null,
            "123",
            React.createElement(Component, null)
        )
    ),
    React.createElement(Component, null)
];
```

Comment: Thank you for quick answer!
I receive string from server and after I add parts of my message together with components in one array..
Maybe in my case I need to write custom parser from string to react elements

Comment: @AlekseyDubinskiy: Yes, I'm afraid you do.